# Change event is not triggered in the Modal

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to create a date limitation, so that the user cannot select a date less than the current month, however, the event is not being triggered when selecting the date.

```
$('#VencData').on('change', function () {
    console.log("Evento change disparado");
    var dataVencimento = new Date($(this).val());
    var dataAtual = new Date();
    if (dataVencimento < new Date(dataAtual.getFullYear(), dataAtual.getMonth(), 1)) {
        alert('The due date cannot be less than the current month.');
        $(this).val('');
    }
});
```

In the frontend I have the date selector

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="vencimento">Data de Vencimento:</label>
    <input type="date" class="form-control" id="vencimento" name="Nota.Vencimento">
</div>
```

But, not even the log message is displayed in the console, I tried some other alternatives, for example, checking the date and displaying the alert message only when clicking the save button, but that doesn't work either, however, the field is read and save normally in my database.

One point that I don't know if it could be affecting but is interesting to mention is that this field is within a registration modal. I don't know if this can prevent or affect the execution of Js.

My development is in ASP.NET.

I tried changing the event types to Blur and Hide, and validating and displaying the message only when clicking the Save button, but nothing works.

I imagine that perhaps the modal could be affecting execution because, testing similar code outside of this development, the event works.

Comment: The id of the element is `vencimento` but your JS is targeting an element with id `VencData`

Answer (score 0):

-> Attach the event handler to the 'document' and specifying target element(#vencimento) as the second argument of the 'on' method.

-> The event handler will triggered even if the element is added to the dynamically.

-> Follow my code(JavaScript):-

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on('change', '#vencimento', function () {
            console.log("Evento change disparado");
            var dataVencimento = new Date($(this).val());
            var dataAtual = new Date();
            if (dataVencimento < new Date(dataAtual.getFullYear(), dataAtual.getMonth(), 1)) {
                alert('The due date cannot be less than the current month.');
                $(this).val('');
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```